# I cant connect to a Bluemix Database from outside Bluemix

Tags: sql, ibm-cloud

We are trying to connect to a Bluemix SQL Database from outside the Bluemix Cloud (with DataStudio and Db Visualizer) but when I follow the instructions on

this link https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html#data-studio

or this one https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/173196/how-to-connect-from-ibm-data-studio-to-dashdb/?smartspace=bluemix

I always get a `SQL4499N` exception. I cant even ping the server so I believe there is a connectivity issue with our database. I am trying both secure (`50000`) and unsecured (`50001`) ports.

I am taking all the values from `<VCAP_SERVICES>` and have downloaded the relevants DB2 driver and certificate.

Can anyone provide any help?

Comment: Could you provide the full error you are seeing? Also, does it work when you try to connect to dashDB from a Bluemix application?

Comment: It works when we connect to dashDB from another IBM on Cloud application so that makes me think that the DB is not public. Could someone verify that jdbc:db2://159.8.148.42:50001/I3386577:sslConnection=true;", is reachable from outside the cloud?

Comment: Yes, I can reach it using $ nc -w 3 -v 159.8.148.42 50001, result is `Connection to 159.8.148.42 port 50001 [tcp/*] succeeded!`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access the SQL database successfully. There was some maintenance going on the servers that might have caused the failure.  Please monitor the below site to verify any maintenance status.

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Please try again connecting your database and stills see the problem , contact bluemix support or open a ticket.

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#support